# How to specify columns as axes in matplotlib and plot bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have 2 columns, A and B. A should be the X axis and B should be the Y axis and I need to plot bar chart here. I'm using matplotlib.

Tried to plot by code `plt.bar(Df.A, Df.B, align='center', alpha=0.5)`.
But it didn't work

```
plt.bar(Df.A, Df.B, align='center', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. What's the problem?

Comment: AttributeError  --> Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-7534df08abd2> in <module>

This is how the error looks like

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
df.plot.bar(x='A', y='B', rot=0)
```

[bar chart docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

Comment: So if `plt.bar(Df.A, Df.B)` doesn't work, why should `df.plot.bar(x='A', y='B')` suddenly work? (Sure, we cannot know what "doesn't work" means in the question, but I'd say either both work, or both don't.)

Comment: That's what I thought, but also in defendence of the answerer here, one cannot know what does not work, because the question does not show a [mcve] and neither does it provide any other information on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
plt.bar(Df.A, Df.B, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel("A")
plt.ylabel('B')
```

Comment: Nope. The first line of the code gives attribute error